# gcc: error trying to exec 'as': execvp: No such file or directory

Tags: gcc, fortran, gfortran

I was trying to install gcc and gfortran on my intel mac with mountain lion and keep getting the above error when trying to compile the fortran file. gcc doesn't seem to work either with c programs.  This is the error I get with my c program:

```
test.c:1:19: fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
```

I tried typing this into terminal:

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/bin
```

but that did not work.  I added gcc and gfortran to /usr/local/bin instead of /usr/bin.  I downloaded the compilers through hpc.  The files had the given directory structure:

```
/usr/local/bin: contained gcc and gfortran along with other compilers
/uer/local/include/...
/usr/local/lib/...
etc...
```

I pretty much just copied and pasted all the files directly over to the exact same path directories on my computer and ran the export command.  That is all I have done.

Comment: what do you get when you do `which as` at the command line?

Comment: you need binutils (http://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/)

Comment: ok, I downloaded binutils but I am not exactly sure where to put it.

Comment: also, this is the error I got from trying to compile a c program:   test.c:1:19: fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory

Comment: you can put `as` near `gcc`, i.e., in the same directory.

Comment: Operating system is Mac OS Mountain Lion.  There was as.c and as.h located under a gas folder but I dont know if that will help me since c programs are not even executing properly

Comment: Which version did you download? There is the `gcc-mlion.tar.gz` which is specifically for ML. Do you also happen to have `Xcode` installed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fatal error: cannot execute 'as': execvp: no such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56801179/fatal-error-cannot-execute-as-execvp-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 2):

You probably need either odcctools (as provided by macports) or XCode (which contains the Mac "binutils", and the Clang compiler, GCC was discontinued).