# Fatal error: cannot execute 'as': execvp: no such file or directory

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors, compilation, execvp

Whenever I try to compile c/cpp files it gives this error:

```
gcc: fatal error: cannot execute ‘as’: execvp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

I have also tried to include full path of file while compiling but same error occured.
Just to be sure of version mismatch I looked for both gcc and g++ version but both are same,
gcc/g++ version: 9.1.0.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Whomever directed this to superuser... I know of no use for assembler besides being used in programming ;-)

Comment: I've managed to reproduce this error message. It has nothing to do with typos. I wonder what the real reason is for closing this question. Is it just poor moderation?

Comment: This is a legitimate, reproducible and quite useful question given the poor naming of `as` in terms of SEO.  Vote for reopen.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`as` command is from `binutils`. Have you installed this package?

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be gcc not being able to locate as - the GNU assembler.
Try locating it in `/usr/bin/as` that where it should be. If that is where it exists, the order of your `$PATH` variables might be the issue.
Can you output the `$PATH`.

Comment: This information appear to have been covered in a previous answer.

Comment: Some of the comments say otherwise.